# MySQL interfering with Intel TBB setup

Tags: mysql, tbb, intel-ipp

I am installing intel TBB performance library. But before using it, I have to setup the environment variables. A script file is provided which automates this process. But when I try to run the .bat file in the command prompt saying mySQL is not a valid command (look at the screenshot). I don't know how MySQL came into the picture. How do I make the script file run properly.? [image: The problem that I am facing with the script file execution]

I am facing a similar problem when trying to set the environment variables for Intel IPP using a script file.

Comment: looks like an installation bug.

Comment: There can be problems with system PATH. Remove "line 1: @echo off" from tbbvars.bat, rerun the command and analyze script output. You might see something unusual in script's "set" commands.

Comment: I removed the "@echo off" from the tbbvars.bat and ran the following command "tbbvats.bat intel64 vs2015" in the command line. I didn't find anything unusual with the "set" command, but it displayed all the environment variables to be set including their paths.

Comment: It is not clear if you observed "MySQL" related messages or not when you removed `@echo off`. Could you attach the output when `@echo off` is removed?
P.S. I am not sure if StackOverflow rules allow discussions in comments. Sorry if I violate the rules. If so, you can post your question on Intel Developer Zone Forum.

Comment: Yes. I did get the "MySQL" related message when I ran the script without "@echo off". But along with that, It also showed the directories and the environment variables to be set for the given set of arguments (in this case "intel64 vs2015") P.S: I did post the same question in the Intel Developer zone forum.